# Silverlight MVVM conversion from WPF

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

I was reading this article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

And I came across this piece of code in the WPF Demo application that came with the article.

This template applies a CustomerView to an instance of the CustomerViewModel class shown in the main window.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomerViewModel}">  
    <vw:CustomerView />  
</DataTemplate>
```

I substituted the angle brackets for square brackets - not sure how to post them.

The code is in the MainWindowResourses.xaml and the code starts on line 19.

Anyone know how I can do this in Silverlight ?? 
We don't have the DataType and I need to be able to tell the app that this View is associated with this ViewModel - so I can create a tab control with different view like the demo app.

Cheers,

EC

Comment: I just edited your code block for you - can you check it is what you intended? Cheers.

Comment: Yeah that's the business :) I think I found out the problem though. I'm using the MVVM Light toolkit - but I'm not using the Locator part of the application - I think that the locator does what I need - need to read up on it :) Thanks

Comment: I've tagged the question mvvm-light. Laurent Bugnion, the man behind MVVM Light Toolkit, who frequently trawls through here, might have a better insight in the matter.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of WPF implicit styling, where a style is applied to all the controls in the project. This is [not supported in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667317/silverlight-invalid-attribute-type-for-targettypextype-textblock).

To get around this you need to instead place your view controls in the markup and set their DataContext to the viewmodel.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:CustomerViewModel x:Key="theViewModel">  
<Window.Resources>

<vw:CustomerView DataContext={StaticResource theViewModel}/>
```

`theViewModel` doesn't have to come from the resources section, it could be a property in the hosting XAML control/page.

Comment: Ok yeah - but I want to be able to create Views dynamically - like in the article I posted above. I'll have a number of views and they'll be added into a TabControl - so how will I be able to add to my collection of 'Workspaces' and have it render the view correctly ?? BTW I'm using the MVVM Light toolkit...

Comment: Don't think you could that out of the box without requiring something like Prism - http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/ It's worth exploring anyway.

Comment: I haven't tried templating my viewmodels like that, it might.