# Set a property from type 'type' with global style in XAML

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I would like to set a dependency property from type 'Type' in xaml. This will work fine but when I set this value in an implicit or explicit styling then a exception will thrown (unhandled exception).

I created an empty Silverlight application and added a user control (DataFormControl).
Here is the code behind of this control:

```
    public DataFormControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(DataFormControl), null);
    public string Title
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TypeToReflectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TypeToReflect", typeof(Type), typeof(DataFormControl), null);
    public Type TypeToReflect
    {
        get { return (Type)GetValue(TypeToReflectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TypeToReflectProperty, value); }
    }

    public string GetCombo()
    {
        string returnValue = (Title ?? "no title") + " ; " + (TypeToReflect != null ? TypeToReflect.Name : "unkown Type");
        return returnValue;
    }


    private void Refresh_Button(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ResultBox.Text = GetCombo();
    }
```

And here the XAML code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Click="Refresh_Button">Refresh</Button>            
        <TextBlock x:Name="ResultBox" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Now the problem occurres in a control which reference this and use global styling:

```
<StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="local:DataFormControl">
                <Setter Property="Title" Value="Implicit Name" />
                <Setter Property="TypeToReflect" Value="local:DataFormControl" />
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold">Test App</TextBlock>

        <local:DataFormControl Title="123" />
        <local:DataFormControl Title="Kuh" />
        <local:DataFormControl TypeToReflect="local:DataFormControl" />
        <local:DataFormControl  />
    </StackPanel>
```

If I remove the "TypeToReflect"-Setter then all work fine. The global styling for the title property works fine too.

Is this a bug or is there a workaround?

I need the type because I would like to use reflection on it.

*Edit:*

Exception information:

```
Message is always.  [Line: 0 Position: 0]  
ExceptionType: Unhandled Exception  
ExceptionObject: XamlParseException
```

**Stacktrace**:

```
 at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)  
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.ConvertStringToTypedCValue(IntPtr pContext, UInt32 cClrTypeName, String clrTypeName, UInt32 cValue, String value, CValue& outVal, Int32& typeIndex)  
   at MS.Internal.SilverlightTypeConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)  
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.GetManagedPropertyValueFromStyle(Boolean useBuiltInStyle, IManagedPeerBase obj, DependencyProperty property, Object& value)  
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.GetValueFromStyle(DependencyProperty property, Object& value)  
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.EvaluateBaseValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)  
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.EvaluateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, ValueOperation operation)  
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry, ValueOperation operation)  
   at System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(DependencyProperty property)  
   at MS.Internal.FrameworkCallbacks.InvalidateProperty(IntPtr nativeTarget, UInt32 propertyId)
```

InnerException is null.

Comment: What is the `InnerException` of the exception? How does the stack trace look like?

Comment: Take a look at this answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/677285/1161647

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028276/missing-style-triggers-and-xtype-why


You're right. There's a similar solution.

Comment: On this example the type of the style will define. This works for me currently. I can use explicit and implicit styling. But the Setter line for the TypeToReflect-Property not work. I can not find an explain on the referenced link.

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
{x:Type Type}
```

No more text.

Comment: In silverlight I can not use the x:Type keyword I think.